# how to get results of query in another query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomerActivity(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.activity.name
```

I have a filter that gets all the CustomerActivities for a customer:

```
customer_activities = CustomerActivity.objects.filter(customer=customer)
```

What I really need is all the Activity objects based on the results of the customer_activities?

Something like

```
   activities = Activity.objects.filter(activity_in=customer_activities)???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(customeractivity__customer=customer)
```

Read more on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I was looking everywhere for that section as well.  Thank you.

Comment: That link is currently broken, anyone know the new location?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships @chayemor